# What's the difference between SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_HWNDPARENT) and SetParent?

Tags: api, winapi, window, watermark

I need to create a watermark window(markHwnd) for some application windows on desktop, the watermark window style is:

```
            uint dwStyle = Win32API.WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |
                          Win32API.WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
                          Win32API.WS_POPUP;
            uint dwExStyle = Win32API.WS_EX_LAYERED |
                            Win32API.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT |
                            Win32API.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE |
                            Win32API.WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY |
                            Win32API.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
            markHwnd = Win32API.CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, wndclassRegResult, ti.ToString(), dwStyle, 0, 0, 0, 0,IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, wndclasshInstance, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Then I will set it to be an owned window of the application window(targetHwnd), there're two choices:

- SetWindowLongPtr(markHwnd, (int)Win32API.GWL.GWL_HWNDPARENT,
  targetHwnd);
- SetParent(markHwnd, targetHwnd);

Which one is suggested?

Comment: There's not much of a difference: Either one will fail. See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Answer (score 3):

The [`SetWindowLongPtr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) documentation says:

> Do not call SetWindowLongPtr with the GWLP_HWNDPARENT index to change the parent of a child window. Instead, use the SetParent function.

What this documentation is alluding to is that `GWLP_HWNDPARENT` actually changes the *owner* of a top-level window, not the *parent* of a child window. According to Raymond Chen:

[A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613)

> Now, a window can have a parent, or it can have an owner, or it can have neither, but it can never have both.

And he goes on to explain how `CreateWindow/Ex()` assigns an owner vs a parent depending on whether the new window has the `WS_CHILD` style or not.

The [`SetParent()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) documentation says:

> For compatibility reasons, SetParent does not modify the WS_CHILD or WS_POPUP window styles of the window whose parent is being changed.

So, `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_HWNDPARENT)` is used to change the *owner of a top-level window*, and `SetParent()` is used to change the *parent of a child window*.

Comment: however `SetWindowLongPtr` with the `GWLP_HWNDPARENT` also have visible effect - it by fact set owner (but not parent). and unlike `SetParent` not change `WS_CHILD` style. for top-level windows i be say use `GWLP_HWNDPARENT` more suitable compare `SetParent`. what and why is documentation say is another story