# How can I change the owner of a Windows window?

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop

I have a floating window that is owned by my app's main frame window. Now, I have created a new frame window and I want to change the owner of the floating window to the new frame window I created. But, I have not been able to find a way to do so.

Essentially, as a user activates either of my frame windows, I want to make the newly activated frame the owner of the floating window.

I tried SetParent hoping if I didn't change the style of the floating window from WS_POPUP to WS_CHILD, that would be a trick that would work but the floating window just fails to display after doing that. And, it is actually becomes a child window in that it shows up when enumerating the child windows of the frame I passed to SetParent.

Is it possible to change the owner of a window after calling CreateEx where I pass in the initial owner?

Comment: See [What's the difference between SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_HWNDPARENT) and SetParent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431689/5538420). Use the former, just make sure the new owner is `WS_POPUP` or `WS_OVERLAPPED`.